What are "fingers in face"?
In this YouTube video, "How to Write Emails Like a White Lady", the  speaker explains a character called Audrina, who is on one end of a spectrum where Karen, the meme, is on the other end.

and we're gonna really channel  our inner Audrina today. Karen and Audrina have something in common. They both want something, and they're gonna wanna speak to a manager about it, but Audrina's gonna get it, and it's because, instead of fingers in face, we have fingers on keyboard.

What does fingers in face mean?

Does "fingers in face" mean "inhibited and embarrassed", moving to "fingers on keyboard" – "relaxed and expressive", or perhaps "back in control"?

... "fingers in face" seems to be literally what people do: hide their face behind their hands.

I suggest that "fingers in face" is a description of someone taking an aggressive face to face stance and literally waving / pointing their finger(s) in someone's face, possibly berating them at the same time.
"fingers on keyboard" is the suggested alternative, writing a letter / email of complaint when you will have time to calm down a bit and put forward a better reasoned argument which may get a more sympathetic response.

I think it's clumsy. We wag a finger in someone's face, but use fingers on a keyboard.

@MichaelHarvey I agree, the obvious phrase "wag a finger" eluded me when I wrote my answer. I should have included it.

Whether you're wagging or pointing your finger, there seems to be only one finger involved: the index finger. Does fingers in the plural here mean repeated action?

Unless fingers in face is supposed to mean either a fist or just that the accusing person's entire hand is near the face of the employee/manager. Using fingers in face is...artistic license.
